# Must I leave the classroom to pray?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings

Salam alykum brothers and sisters,

My question is at the time of prayer must I leave the classroom to go pray or is it permissible to wait until after the class to pray?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the class end before the time of the prayer ends?

Comment: For some classes yes and some no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Shi'a Islam, Salat is one of the most important pillars and has to be performed in it's time.

The 8th Imam, 'Ali ibn Musa al-Rida (peace be upon him) said: "O' so and so! Whenever the time for Salat sets in, recite it, for you do not know what will happen (after that time)."

The Holy Prophet(blessings of Allah be upon him and his family) said the best of the deeds in the eyes of Allah(Glorified is He)are the Salawat( five daily Salat) in their prime times and after that, doing goodness to one' s father and mother and after that, the best act is Jihad (struggle) in the way of Allah (Glorified and Exalted is He)."

It is narrated from Imam Hasan al-Askari (peace be upon him) that prophet Musa (peace be upon him) in his whispered prayer to Allah (Glorified is He) used to say, "O' Allah! What is the reward for one who performs his Salat in its proper time?" Allah (Glorified and Exalted is He) replied, "Whatever he asks from Me, I will give it to him and I will make heaven permissible for him."

Thus, if the class ends during the prescribed time, you may wait for it to end and then perform the prayer, otherwise it is better to be excused for the class to perform salat.